# Hide a UL when a url is loaded

Tags: javascript, animation

i am having a form -search below that on search i am listing the matched records below the search form .. But even by default case without any search when i load the search form i am getting all the entries by default..

which is coming in a UL.. So i am trying to hide a div when the particular url is loaded .. How to do so??

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

you can type

```
.(class/id name){
display:none;
```

}

then add the class/id name to the starting tag of the UL you want to hide, and that will hide the whole UL and that is in HTML and CSS

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to check whether there is some data in the POST (search has been commited) or not. If it has, show the ul or hide otherwise, here is the prototype in php:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST))
{?>
   <ul>
       <li>....</li>
       <li>....</li>
       <li>....</li>
       // etc
   </ul>
<?php } ?>
```